# Date Repeat Node Generator Module

Tags: datetime

I have a Drupal 6 site and am looking for a way to allow my content admins to set up repeat events. I have that set up, but all the repeats are not their own node. I want them to be their own node, so they will appear in my calendar block and in my views on their respective dates.

I've not been able to find a solution in Drupal 6. I found several modules and this one looks promising, but it doesn't seem to be working:
https://www.drupal.org/project/date_repeat_nodegen

The module's page on Drupal says:

> As part of the node editing form, you'll see a question prompting you
>   to "Generate each date as a single node". Answering yes (the default)
>   will ceate one node for each date in the repeating pattern you've
>   specified, as determined by the Date Repeat API. Each node may be
>   edited separately after creation and used in views. Answering no will
>   create a single node using the repeating pattern, essentially
>   disabling this feature for the node.

But once I activate the module and create a new event, I don't see this question in my form. :-(

Can anyone help me be either showing me a better way of doing this or by helping get this module working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I wanted to post that I figured this out. You have to go to the content type and enable "Repeat". For me it was in the vertical tabs of the Events content type. Once I did that and set it to the date field it worked. BUT the Date Repeat section in the Events content type edit form did NOT work. I just ignored this section altogether and once I create the single event and save, a tab appears above the content titled "Repeat." When I click on that, I see basically the same settings as I did when creating the node, but this time they actually work!!! –